# Why don't my big arrows appear at the end of the line segments and how can I fix this?

Tags: tikz-arrows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,line width=1]
%
\tikzstyle{a}=[
    decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{>}}},
    postaction={decorate},
    shorten >=9pt, shorten <=9pt,
    ] 
\coordinate (u1) at (1,1);
\coordinate (u2) at (2,2);
\coordinate (u3) at (1,0);
\node[outer sep=10pt,rectangle,draw] at (u1) {\qquad};
\node[outer sep=10pt,rectangle,draw] at (u2) {\qquad};
\node[outer sep=10pt,rectangle,draw] at (u3) {\qquad};
\draw[a] (u1)--(u2);
\draw[a] (u3)--(u1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: arrows]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are shortening the arrows by `9pt` and decorating at position `1`. Hence arrow tips are at position `1` and the segment is shorter. You have to decorate at appropriate position (like 0.83) which will be ugly anyway. Here is an alternative:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,line width=1]
%
\tikzstyle{a}=[
    %shorten >=9pt, shorten <=9pt,
    decoration={markings,mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{>}}},
    postaction={decorate},    
    ]
%\coordinate (u1) at (1,1);
%\coordinate (u2) at (2,2);
%\coordinate (u3) at (1,0);
\node[outer sep=5pt,rectangle,draw] at (1,1)(u1)  {\qquad};
\node[outer sep=5pt,rectangle,draw] at (2,2) (u2)  {\qquad};
\node[outer sep=5pt,rectangle,draw] at  (1,0) (u3)  {\qquad};
\draw[a] (u1)--(u2);
\draw[a] (u3)--(u1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, I have adjusted the `outer sep` (any way you keep them high) and instead of `coordinate`s I have directly defined `node`s so that `node`s can be connected (not the `coordinate`s). By adjusting `outer sep` suitably, you can change the length of arrows. If you have to connect some thing to the center of these nodes, use `(u1.center)` etc.

Comment: Thanks Harish Kumar that worked perfectly in my larger diagram, but I don't quite understand it. So details would be nice.

Comment: @DonKreher Can you be specific on which part you didn't understand?

Comment: @ Harish Kumar. Well what you have added above helps. I guess I don't understand this use of nodes.  It seemed to me that defining a node at a coordinate vs associating a coordinate at a node should be the same. Apparently they are not.  I must have some fundamental misunderstanding. What should I read?

Comment: @DonKreher `node`s have `inner` and `outer seperations`. while coordinates don't. Read: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=difference+between+nodes+and+coordinates.